# I am getting error message as " [ArmDisarm] invalid level_name or level_values "

Tags: google-home, google-smart-home

Not able to start my google test suite
[image]
strong text

Comment: Have you verified your SYNC response is [valid](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/tools/validator)?

Comment: I had a mistake in my sync response. The field name should be level_name and level_values. Once I have updated my values in the response. The suite started working.

Answer (score 0):

[Test Suite](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/tools/smart-home-test-suite?hl=en) works by doing three sets of tests for each trait/attribute on your device:
It sends your fulfillment endpoint an execution request, then waits for a report state to come back to Google (your report state response)
It makes a query to your fulfillment endpoint, then waits for the response for the query (your query response)
It then checks if your report state response matches the query response.

The image you showed contains a failure when starting the test suite. It looks like your
sync response might contain an error. You can always use [Google Home Sync Validator](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/tools/validator)
to check if your sync response is valid.